# CoreData Performance with Relation (RemoteID and internal ID)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have lots of CoreData Models with relations - for example:

A Task could have Persons, Groups, Images, ..

Normally i would use here the CoreData Relations if a user creates a new object with a relation. like:

```
let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Images", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Image
object.relation = whatever (NSManagedObject)
```

So CoreData created in SQLite an Relation, an numeric ID.

And with a predicate i can easy get all related Objects when ill use the NSManagedObject in a where clause.

But, now i need to sync a lot of Models with a Backend, and it is much better to use the RemoteID for relations. Like:

```
let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Images", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Image
object.taskid = 'dhjfdsf-31232-321das321-3232'
```

if ill now use a predicate (and there are lots of data) - makes in ANY performance difference when ill use as filter my RemoteIDs (GUIDs) ?

So should i create not any relations in CoreData (because i dont need them anymore) and do not run in performance issues? Makes that any difference to get all objects in CoreData with a predicate as (String) here, or with an related  NSManagedObject?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create local as well as remote ids. With local ones, the performance of the app will be good, and remote ones can be used to filter out the local objects w.r.t server.(i.e. to update any particular object, or to delete all local child/relational objects which are no more require with parent model). In this way, your synchronization process will be handled.